# How to define ARIMA parameters if some values of autocorrelation is too high?

Tags: time-series, python, arima, autocorrelation

I know, that parameters p, q, P and Q can be founded using autocorrelograms. As I understand q is the number of the last significant lag in the autocorrelogram, and p is the number of the last significant lag in the partial autocorrelogram.

Here's my graphs:

[image: my graphs]

So, should I set q to 1 and p to 2?

I have some doubts, because 2<sup>nd</sup> autocorrelation is very low, but the 3<sup>rd</sup> is significant enough.

---

The seasonality of the data is equal to 12

Comment: My suggestion is that your run auto.arima and see what this suggest. The classical approach you use, some believe, does not work well with real world data especially if you have both p and q. Q by the way refers to moving averages and p is ar terms, but using the classical approach to do this is a lot more complicated than you show. You have to look at many things at the same time to determine this not just the ACF and PACF.

Comment: `auto.arima` has default bounds for parameters. Without understanding of parameters' approximate value `auto.arima` doesn't work

Comment: I have never encountered this, or seen it suggested in the literature on auto.arima. That is interesting. That is I did not see anything that suggested it had to know approximate values. It just tests all models below a certain level and determines which has the lowest AIC. Given the general comments that AR and MA in the social sciences rarely are beyond 3 it makes sense to me.